# вывод данных по столбцу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

как сделать так чтобы был вывод не такой как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А отдел1 выводился один раз и все кто состоят в этом отделе, и так далее?

Вывожу так, немогу понять как сделать

```
$sql = "SELECT extension, name, departaments FROM users order by departaments";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["departaments"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]." ".$row["extension"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Запоминать предыдущий отдел, и проверять - если совпадает с текущим, то не выводить.

Comment: @Ипатьев можете подсказать как это сделать? или ссылочку или код

Comment: Есть. Разумеется, есть ссылочка. Потому что вы не первый, перед кем встаёт такая проблема. И на этот вопрос уже отвечали много. И всё что нужно, чтобы узнать ответ - это умение пользоваться интернетом

Comment: @Ипатьев ну так подскажите пожалуйста, я ищу невыводить повторящиеся строки столбцы итд, вроде есть distinct и прочее, но оно просто не выводит всю строку со всеми данными, т.е. name и extension тоже не выводятся

Comment: @reddyk А при чём здесь distinct? Вы получаете из mysql полный набор данных, а уже в php программируете отслеживать повтор значения для первой колонки.

Comment: я подсказал же уже, ссылка висит в самом верху